# Charts using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to design a pie chart using jquery,html,css how?
how to get daily report in pie chart representation using the code.
By 
Teja

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   var test=new Array();
      function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url:'getData.php',
  type:'GET',
        dataType:'json',
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  async:false,
  success: function(data){
         test=data;
   }
        }).responseText;
   //alert(test);
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(test);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
    pieHole: 0.6,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I am not able to get any out put 
and i am getting all json data using different file and getting json data using Ajax code in my code ... is there any other way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be getting anything because `$.ajax` is asynchronous, meaning that when you call it, it starts a request, and then immediately continues to the next statement (before any data is even returned)

If all goes well, you end up in the method you assigned to `success`.
That is where you should be drawing your chart.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

function drawChart() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'getData.php',
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        async:false,
        success: function(data){
            var options = {
                title: 'My Daily Activities',
                pieHole: 0.6,
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
            var dataAsDataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
            chart.draw(dataAsDataTable, options);
        }
    });    
}


//typically it is a good idea to define functions or variables *before*
//passing them as a reference. i am not quite sure what the code below will do,
//but since it references the drawChart function, it should be executed after
//defining drawChart.

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Comment: Hi Groote, the code u have given was executed but graph is not displaying, and no errors are coming..Can you give different code to display pie chart with daily progress

Comment: and nice Answer but some were i am doing a mistake like ... we are passing test as parameter, but we declare test as an empty array then how the data will pass to the dataAsDataTable. i Want little clarity here... can you plz give me

Comment: sorry, that should have been the `data` variable returned in the success handler. (slight overlook on my part) i have updated the answer.

Comment: you will no longer need your `test` variable. by the way.

Comment: ok when i am using data behalf of test it is not displaying any thing ... so plz give me any other code incase of this code... or any modification in my code

Comment: @Tej i'm not sure i follow. your test variable wasn't useful in any way, since it would always return an empty array where you called it.

Comment: What i posted should work based on what you have told me. does it not?

Comment: sry.... i am telling that if you are having any different program about charts application plz share that to me..groote

Comment: I don't get what you mean by 'different program about chats application'. are you looking for other charting libraries?

Comment: yes... i am locking for another  code to generate charts.

Comment: that question is off topic as far as i'm concerned. be sure to read up on how to ask SO questions, and in this case : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource

Comment: I am new to stack overflow ... next time i will try like that .........thank you  Groote